# Using jQuery Ajax to display email sent successfully

Tags: jquery, ajax, contact-form

I have written a contact form and php script which sends the e-mail find but when the message is sent it reloads a new page.

I would like to use Ajax to to display a message to user when the message is sent instead of going to a new page

Any ways to easily do this with Jquery ?

My form :

```
      <form id="cont-form" method="post" action="mail.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Send me a message</legend>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Eg. 07500000000" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Eg. Enquiry" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Insert your message or question" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="human">Enter the number 4 if you're human</label>
        <input id="human" name="human" type="text" placeholder="Are you human?" required>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send it!">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

My php script :

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name']; //'name' has to be the same as the name value on the form input element
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $human = $_POST['human'];
   $from = $_POST['email'];
   $to = 'ben_humphries@hotmail.co.uk'; //set to the default email address
   $subject = $_POST['subject'];
   $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

   $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
   "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
   "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

   if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['human']) == '4') {               
   mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);  //mail sends it to the SMTP server side which    sends the email
   echo "<p>Your message has been sent!</p>";
   } 

   else { 
   echo "<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>"; 
   } 
   if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['human']) != '4') {
   echo "<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Create a `$.ajax` call for your PHP file above, once the email has been sent, `echo` back what you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup. You need to do a couple of things:

1- Change the submit button, so it calls a JQuery/Javascript function that does the AJAX call:

```
<button class="button" id="submit" name="submit">Send it!</button>
```

You can either set a onclick on the HTML or bind the click event in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //this is executed when the document is fully loaded
     $("#submit").click(function(){
         $.post("mail.php", $("#cont-form").serialize(), function(data){
              //this is a callback function, when the AJAX calls ends anything 
              //echoed by mail.php goes into the data variable it receives.
              alert(data);
         });
     });
});
```

2- Change `mail.php` to echo the message you want to `alert()`. In your case it may work already. If you are returning HTML code maybe it's better to display it inside a `div` instead of doing an `alert()`.

Comment: I have added the jquery like you stated and the page is still loading in another page and there is no alert, Will the start of the form action need to be changed as this is linked directly to the php file

Comment: you have to change the HTML of the submit input as well!

Comment: yeah so the jquery is being called when the button with id of "submit" is clicked, the buttons id is already submit, does the form action="mail.php" need to be changed ?

Comment: the problem here is you are using a `input` tag with `submit` type. clicking this will submit the form and load the new page, we don't want that, so you have to remove this input and use a button tag instead.